# SwiftLint Warning: File Name Violation. How can I fix it?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am using SwiftLint to clean up my code formatting of the project. I met a File Name Violation warning. I tried many ways but I can't fix it.

Those are what I did:

1. Create a class -> LoginPageViewController.
2. Got a warning -> Length of class name should be between 3 and 20 characters long.
3. Refactor the name of this class as LoginController everywhere.
4. Run and got a warning: File Name Violation. Seems like the name still keeps the original one.
5. Try to clean build folder, still doesn't work.
6. Try to delete the file and recreate a new file with a totally different name, but the same warning with the same name LoginPageViewController is still showing.

[image]

The filename has already been changed to LoginController.

[image]

Please help me out. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why have you created such a rule? 20 isn't that much for a filename when you want to include the type in the file namne, like viewController. Change the rule instead of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you don't want to change the file name or the class name you can deactivate the "file_name"-rule in your *.swiftlint.yml* for defined files like this:

```
file_name: 
  excluded: ["MyClass1.swift", "MyClass2.swift", "MyClass3.swift"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name remains as `LoginPageViewController.swift`. Rename it to `LoginController.swift` as the class.

Then, do `Cmd + Shift + K` to clean the build folder and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the file name has already been changed to LoginController.swift.

Comment: Try to clean the build folder Cmd + Shift + K

Answer (score 0):

Update: Seems this issue has occurred due to unsuccessful rename. Copy all the code in this file and delete this file. Create a new Swift file named `LoginController` and paste the copied code into it.

A simple solution to avoid this warning is to create an empty declaration for `LoginPageViewController`. Like this:

```
enum LoginPageViewController { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will cause another warning, Type name violation since the type name should be between 3 and 20 characters long.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have tried to create a new file with a totally different name, but interesting thing is, the same error will still show up.

Comment: Did you make sure the old file is deleted from your project?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the warning in the any file, below code can be added in the first line of the file.

```
// swiftlint:disable:this file_name
```